# ¿Por qué envío de información desde formulario me inserta el mismo valor numérico en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario de registro que envía información a una base de datos MySQL, y este envío de información lo proceso mediante PHP en un archivo distinto al documento HTML con la vista del formulario.

El problema es que tengo dos campos de tipo `tel` que al ser registrados en la base de datos siempre aparece el mismo dato numérico siguiente: `2147483647`.

Específicamente los dos campos que están presentando este problema son `celular` y `tarjeta`, los cuales se encuentran de la siguiente manera en su archivo HTML:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="celular">Celular</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar numero celular" name="celular" id="celular" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="correo">Correo</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar correo electrónico" name="correo" id="correo" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar fecha de nacimiento" name="nacimiento" id="nacimiento" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="rfc">RFC</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar numero RFC" name="rfc" id="rfc">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tarjeta">Numero de Tarjeta Bancaria</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar numero de tarjeta" name="tarjeta" id="tarjeta">
                        <small class="text-muted"> Será la cuenta a la cual se te realizarán los depositos de tus ganancias</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tarjeta2">Confirmar Tarjeta Bancaria</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Vuelva a ingresar el numero de tarjeta" name="tarjeta2" id="tarjeta2" required>
                    </div>
```

Y la información rellenada es procesada mediante una consulta preparada de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
//Asignacion de valor a variables
$nombre = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['nombre']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$apellido = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['apellido']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$cdc = $_POST['cdc'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$nacimiento = $_POST['nacimiento'];
$rfc = $_POST['rfc'];
$rfc = strtoupper($rfc);
$tarjeta = $_POST['tarjeta'];
$tarjeta2 = $_POST['tarjeta2'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

/* ... */

 //Envio de la informacion por medio de consultas preparadas     
 $consulta = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO meseros (
 codmesero,
 idm,
 cdc,
 lider,
 nombre,
 apellidos,
 pass,
 celular,
 correo,
 nacimiento,
 rfc,
 tarjeta,
 foto
 ) VALUES (
 :codmesero,
 null,
 :cdc,
 false,
 :nombre,
 :apellidos,
 :pass,
 :celular,
 :correo,
 :nacimiento,
 :rfc,
 :tarjeta,
 null
 )');

 $consulta->execute(array(
 ':codmesero' => $codmesero,
 ':cdc' => $cdc,
 ':nombre' => $nombre,
 ':apellidos' => $apellido,
 ':pass' => $pass,
 ':celular' => $celular,
 ':correo' => $correo,
 ':nacimiento' => $nacimiento,
 ':rfc' => $rfc,
 ':tarjeta' => $tarjeta
 ));

 //Agregue esto para limpiar las variables, pero el problema persiste
 $cdc = '';
 $nombre = '';
 $apellido = '';
 $pass = '';
 $celular = '';
 $correo = '';
 $nacimiento = '';
 $rfc = '';
 $tarjeta = '';
```

Ya he intentado cambiar el tipo de input de `tel` a `text` pero no soluciona nada, sigue enviando el mismo numero a la base de datos, y precisamente solo esos dos campos.

Comment: De qué tipo son los campos en la base de datos? Es posible que los hayas puesto, por ejemplo, el campo tarjeta como numérico entero y el valor que está guardando el es valor máximo de un integer. Sí es así lo que deberías hacer es cambiar el tipo del campo en la base de datos además de en el formulario.

Comment: ¿Podrías enviarnos el resultado de un `DESCRIBE CREATE TABLE meseros`? Todo apunta a que son campos numéricos a los que tratas de introducir un número superior a su capacidad, desbordando su contenido y fijándose al [límite superior del tipo `INT` (`2^11 - 1`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Comment: Fe de erratas: `(2^31 - 1)` (número positivo más grande en un número de 32 bits, 4 octetos). Si nos proporcionas el resultado del `DESCRIBE CREATE TABLE meseros` lo podremos confirmar. Y si te permiten modificar la tabla, te podría indicar cómo convertir esos campos a texto para que puedas introducir libremente texto o números hasta el número de caracteres deseado.

Comment: Gracias a ambos Alejandro y OscarGarcia, justamente era ese el problema. Tenia un campo de tipo INT, lo cual generaba el problema al desbordar su capacidad, solucionandolo tal como me lo hiciste saber @OscarGarcia. Gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que los campos `celular` y `tarjeta` de tu tabla son de tipo `INT` (32 bits o 4 octetos), cuyo [límite superior es `2^31 - 1 = 2147483647`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Para solucionarlo deberías convertir los campos en:

- `BIGINT`: Su contenido podría llegar hasta `2⁶³-1` ocupando 64 bits u 8 octetos.
- `CHAR(n)`: Su contenido podría contener números o letras hasta `n` caracteres.

Puedes usar [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-examples.html) para modificar el contenido de dichos campos es:

```
ALTER TABLE meseros
  MODIFY celular BIGINT,
  MODIFY tarjeta BIGINT;
```